# Displaying complex outputs

Tags: php, yii, param

I'm using Yii as a framework and I'm having trouble with this piece of code.

I want to output the apartments which has a "status" of "occupied"

So I have this CHtml link with querystring parameters

```
<?php echo CHtml::link('Occupied Apartments', array('/apartments/','status'=>'occupied')); ?>
```

But it still displays ALL outputs even if the status is "available". What must be the problem?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: can you just show the code of the action where this link takes you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to construct the link as

```
   http://yourdomain.com/controller/action/status/xyzStatus
```

For this, First you have configure this URL structure in [urlManager](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url) in your config file ie, main.php in protected/config/

Just add bellow line in urlManager rules

```
  '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<status:([A-Za-z0-9-]+)>' => '<controller>/<action>',
```

Finally your basic url rules will appear as

```
   'rules' => array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<status:([A-Za-z0-9-]+)>' => '<controller>/<action>', //This is newly added line
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        ),
```

Now your url will work. You can get the status value with `$_GET['status'];`

Answer (score 0):

Please filter your data provider with $_GET['status']; mostly on conditions with CActiveDataProvider .